# try to set the frame of subview on UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, iphone

I try to use the code below to set the position and size of subview(image and view) on an UICollectionViewCell

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {

        //wangzheng +
        self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
        if (self) {
            NSArray *nibView =  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"IndexCityMicroCosmeticCell"owner:self options:nil];
            UIView *bw = [nibView objectAtIndex:0] ;

            [self.contentView addSubview:bw];
            [bw setFrame:self.contentView.bounds];

            //wangzheng +

            if (IS_IPHONE_6P || IS_IPHONE_6) {

                _scaleRate=1.5;
            }
            else{
                _scaleRate=1;
            }

            img1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120*_scaleRate, 151*_scaleRate);

            NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f  ",img1.frame.origin.x,img1.origin.y,img1.frame.size.width,img1.frame.size.height);
            img2.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 0, 200*_scaleRate, 85*_scaleRate);
            img3.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 84*_scaleRate, 200*_scaleRate, 67*_scaleRate);


            bottomView.frame=CGRectMake(0,150*_scaleRate, 320*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);
            imgAnnounce.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 119*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);
            anUIView.frame=CGRectMake(119*_scaleRate, 0, 201*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);


        }
        return self;
    }
    return self;
}
```

[image]

I checked and found that the value are right, but they do not relocate immediately.

[image]

images fit to the UICollectionViewCell, but does not follow UICollectionViewCell  to increase/adjust the size of UICollectionViewCell

Your comment welcome

Comment: Where are your allocating `img1`.. etc? when did this takes effect after reload? have you tried placing the code inside `- (void)layoutSubviews` ?

Comment: try moving your code inside `-drawRect`

Comment: please list your info as the answer, I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where are your allocating img1.. etc? when did this takes effect after reload? have you tried placing the code inside `- (void)layoutSubviews` ?

if yes...

try moving your code inside `-drawRect`to perform custom drawing/ui update..  and call `setNeedsDisplay` to trigger `drawRect` and redraw the components/UI

Comment: execellent, this is only way to draw uicollectionview on fly

Answer (score 0):

You should set the position and size of subviews when the size of the  cell(cell.contentView) changes, try to use `layoutSubviews`:

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    [bw setFrame:self.contentView.bounds];

    //wangzheng +

    if (IS_IPHONE_6P || IS_IPHONE_6) {

        _scaleRate=1.5;
    }
    else{
        _scaleRate=1;
    }

    img1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120*_scaleRate, 151*_scaleRate);

    NSLog(@"%f %f %f %f  ",img1.frame.origin.x,img1.origin.y,img1.frame.size.width,img1.frame.size.height);
    img2.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 0, 200*_scaleRate, 85*_scaleRate);
    img3.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 84*_scaleRate, 200*_scaleRate, 67*_scaleRate);

    bottomView.frame=CGRectMake(0,150*_scaleRate, 320*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);
    imgAnnounce.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 119*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);
    anUIView.frame=CGRectMake(119*_scaleRate, 0, 201*_scaleRate, 24*_scaleRate);
}
```

or set the `autoresizingMask` of the subviews (image and view) in the `initWithFrame`, like so:

```
img1.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 120*_scaleRate, 151*_scaleRate);
img1.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
…
img2.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 0, 200*_scaleRate, 85*_scaleRate);
img2.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

img3.frame=CGRectMake(120*_scaleRate, 84*_scaleRate, 200*_scaleRate, 67*_scaleRate);
img3.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin | img2.autoresizingMask
...
```